# Is there any function to resize oryginal image to specyfic size?

Tags: wordpress

Based on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size I can set image size with add_image_size(). But my question is how can I set size for oryginal image. I just don't need to store images bigger then 1024x768. I have too much files with 2560x1440 (about 3 MB) and I never use that. Is there any function to resize oryginal image to specyfic size?

Comment: Maybe this https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-image-resizer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darku, you can use bulk resize media plugin for it. if you have wordpress version below or 3.8.3 then it will work for it. I did not check it with 3.9 but you can try on 3.9 as well.
Please find the plugin link https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-resize-media/